# What I can't do with keytool that I can do with OpenSSL?  

Tags: java, cryptography, openssl, keytool

Though my project is java based but we still use OpenSSL to generate keys and certificate. I don't understand how OpenSSL is better then java keystore.

What I can't do with keytool, that I can do with OpenSSL?

Comment: Uh... really? OK, well... how about properly sign an X509 CSR with constraints? Or what about doing actual encryption of a file using AES? Or elliptic curve cryptography? Or interoperability between the many different kinds of keystores and certificates? Decent random number generation? I could go on.

Comment: Keytool is a tool for managing keys. It's not an encryption suite. The fact that it can generate certificates only encourages people to be sloppy. I'm not saying OpenSSL is the be-all-end-all of encryption suites, but Keytool is to OpenSSL what a tricycle is to a tank.

Comment: @chris: I would describe the openssl command line tool as a crypto swiss army knife, whereas keytool is designed for managing java keystores only. By the way, I think finally the Java 7 keytool can create CSRs with the constraints you are referring to. Amazing that it took so long to get there.

Comment: @GregS you'll notice I qualified my statement about CSR signing. It's true that it can sign them, but its support for extensions is embarassing. I recently tried using as a CA with very bad results. It's still got a ways to go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your needs.

If you just need to generate a self-signed certificate for testing purposes with no extensions (like in `X.509 v1` certificates) then IMO it is much faster and convenient to use `Keytool` (**Note**: I have no idea about if additions/changes have been introduced in `Keytool` in Java 7).

Additionally if you need just to manage your certificates or use `JKS` keystores, `Keytool` is still the way to go.

Other than that, you would need to use a robust security facility which would be certainly OpenSSL.

Note that if you just need to generate -fast- certificates/keystores for your testing you could use a Java based tool e.g. [Certificate Helper](http://sourceforge.net/projects/certhelper/) which also creates extensions.

But for production/interoperability and all the reasons mentioned by friends in the comments you would use OpenSSL.